How to generate md documentation for vue files
I now need to the company's business components to generate md documents, the use of vue, packaged with vite, there is no good plug-ins?
I tried to use Microsoft's @microsoft/api-extractor plugin to generate documents, but this plugin mainly generates documents for ts files, and many of our company's business components such as props are defined in vue files, so it doesn't apply to me, I don't know if there's a good solution.

You could use Vitepress if you want to have some markdown documentation and Vue components inside of it, Nuxt content also does that. Otherwise, you probably need to roll some kind of unified.js parser like this one. The Vite/Vue part are then not mandatory because it will mostly just take a string as an input and do the rest given how you mix the plugins together.

My ultimate goal is to generate md files and put them into vitepress, and now I'm wondering if I can automatically generate md through code.

Yeah definitely can, depends on your input.
